# Undo SSH Key-Based Authentication

Tags: debian, ssh-agent

I'm using a Debian 11 (Bullseye) with Gnome Desktop.

For testing I implemented a SSH key-based authentication by creating a key-pair (transferring the public key to the remote host) and modifying `~/.ssh/config` like this:

```
Host server
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/server_id_rsa
```

Everything is working fine and I can login to the remote host (using the key) without password.

---

To switch back to the original behavior I removed the above two lines from `~/.ssh/config`.
However, I can still login (via ssh) without password.

A restart does not solve the problem.

I don't want to delete the key because it is needed somewhere else ...
... and I guess that this problem is somehow related to the **Debian bug** [472477](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=472477)

---

So, how can I **undo** SSH key-based authentication without deleting the key?

(Waiting for the bug to be resolved is not an option since this bug is present since 15 years now.)

**EDIT**:
I just found out that when I remote login to the computer everything works as expected (key-based authentication does **not** work when I remove `~/.ssh/config`) - however, when using a Gnome terminal key-based authentication is still present.

Comment: your ssh agent might just still be holding on to working credentials; restart it and this might simply go away.

Comment: Unfortunately, a restart does not solve the problem.

Comment: hm, there's more to that bug report

Comment: can you tell us what `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` gives? and maybe also `lsof $SSH_AUTH_SOCK`.

Comment: `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` gives `/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh`. `lsof $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` gives `lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1001/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.`

Comment: Check that your public key did not get placed in ~/.ssh/id_rsa  -  this is the default location when no IdentityFile is specified.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - my key (public and privat) is stored in ~/.ssh/

Comment: ... @truth yes but what is its *name*? is it really `server_id_rsa` or is it actually `id_rsa` (the default)? FYI if all else fails you can add `-o PubkeyAuthentication=no` to your ssh command.

Comment: The key name is not the default `id_rsa`. I can add `-o PubkeyAuthentication=no` to my ssh command but this is not the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution for my problem:

- Create a new folder `~/.ssh/backup` and copy the relevant key (public and private) from `~/.ssh` into this new folder
- Use Gnome (or run seahorse from cli) to remove the relevant key from the key-list (this will remove the key from `~/.ssh`)
- reboot computer
- Copy the relevant key back into `~/.ssh`

After this the key will be visible also in Gnome (seahorse) - however, the problem (that key-based authentication is present without having any entry in `~/.ssh/config`) is gone.